# ¿Alguna alternativa a ConcurrentHashMap? Lento con grandes valores

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy transformando mi aplicación para que trabaje con múltiples Hilos envés de un Hilo, pero no he podido encontrar un mapa que trabaje en múltiples Hilos y no genere degradación en el rendimiento debido a Valores muy grandes en el mapa.

ConcurrentHashMap y HashMap, iteran encima de los Valores y las Llaves cuando uso el método `get()` o `containsKey()`, en cambio, los mapas de `gnu.trove` solo iteran encima de las llaves, lo que los hace 4-5 veces mas rápidos que un `hashmap` o `concurrenthashmap`.

Quisiera saber, si alguien conoce un mapa parecido a Trove, que no itere sobre Valores, y sirva para aplicaciones de muchos Hilos, o una forma de prevenir guardar Valores reales en el mapa y colocar Valores de referencia.

> Benchmark(32k String):
>   ConcurrentHashMap tardo 2007ms en usar 100 millones de veces.
>   containsKey gnu.trove.map.hash.TLongObjectHashMap() tardo 408ms en usar 100 millones de veces.
>   containsKey

Mientras mas grande, el tamaño del Objeto Valor, a guardar, mas tarda ConcurrentHashMap.

Nota: Ya he bajado el nivel de concurrencia de `concurrenthashmap` a 1, debido a que itera sobre valores, mas de 1 genera degradación en el rendimiento.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50780/discussion-on-question-by-gonzalo-ciocca-alguna-alternativa-a-concurrenthashmap).